# how to backup contacts if the touchscreen is not working?

Tags: contacts, backup, touchscreen

My HTC Explorer A310e fell and now its touch screen is not working. I mean display is fine, but it isn't taking any input. Is there any way I could take a backup of the contacts?
To suggest the extent  damage: it rings but I can't receive calls.

I am travelling and can't go to a service centre until next week so if there was a way I could get my contacts out of it.

Comment: Could you check if your Google address book (the contacts in `Gmail`) contain the information you're looking for? It may already contain all your contacts if you're set up to synchronize contacts.

Answer (score 1):

in this [link](http://chombium.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/android-how-to-backup-contacts-and-sms-messages/) they provide you with some usefull commands to try to get the contacts.
Basically, you need to install the Android SDK, but I think you need to have the USB debugging option on in your phone. Not sure if you need root also.

```
cd <android-sdk-dir>/platform-tools
[In linux] ./adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
[In Windows] adb.exe pull /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
```

The path to the contacts database might vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: That doesn't require a full SDK install (see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) And it has another show stopper: Usually `adbd` doesn't run in root mode, so `adb pull` has no access to those directories. To work around that, there's the *Insecure ADBD* app on play (and XDA); but to activate that, one needs to push a button -- which hardly can be done with a broken touch screen (except for, maybe, injecting keyevents via ADB).

Comment: The above commands used will not work unless you are rooted IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

from a Forensics background, you could download the ViaExtract virtual machine [which you can download here](https://vp-qa.viaforensics.io/extract/community-edition/).

ViaExtract is a tool that can help recover almost everything from a connected android device n it has an easy-to-use graphical user interface. just connect your device to the virtual machine and start the extraction procedure. it will recover bookmarks, contacts, messages n a lot of other stuff. the above link also has a video tutorial on how to go through the extraction process too.

the configuration process may seem hectic but considering how often people may need help recovering stuff from their phones, it's kinda worth it.

other mobile forensics tools you can use are OSAF or SANTOKU

Answer (score -4):

SAMSUNG KIES worked for me - not rooted, developer mode off, screen not working

Comment: Isn't Samsung Kies only for Samsung phones? It doesn't seem applicable to the HTC device described in the question.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger No, it worked also for my Sony Xperia devices